# Do neutron stars have an ergosphere?

Tags: black-hole, neutron-star

Ergospheres are a property of black holes, and do neutron stars have it? If yes, why seldom article mentions that; if no, why can't neutron stars have this ergosphere component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neutron stars are generally not compact enough to have an ergosphere. Typically, the radius of a neutron star is several times the Schwarzschild radius corresponding to its mass. The ergosphere however starts at the Schwarzschild radius.

Comment: Well, thank you @mmeent, i see.

Comment: In addition, one could say that any object compact enough to have an ergosphere automatically become a black hole.

Comment: @Jonas It is not so simple, since the horizon radius of a spinning black hole can be as small as half the Schwarzschild radius.